# Two questions about vector use

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

I have created a class "firefly" similar to this:

```
class firefly{

private:

   float time_flash;

public:

firefly(int, int, float, float);//parametric constr.
firefly();
firefly(const firefly& a);//copy constructor

void receive_flash(std :: vector<firefly>&, float, float, int);
friend bool operator <(const firefly&) const;
};
```

Focus on the last two functions; I have two question about them.
In the main program I wanted to initialize a vector of fireflies as follows:

```
vector <firefly> fire_vec(10, firefly(5, 5,(float) 1., (float)1.) );
```

using the parametric constructor. Can I do this?
The secondo question.
This vector should be ordered by the algorithm sort,

```
sort(fire_vec.begin(), fire_vec.end());
```

having overloaded operator< as follows:

```
bool operator <(const firefly &rhs) const {return time_flash < rhs.time_flash;}
```

Is there anything wrong in doing this? (i think there is something wrong, because I can't)

Comment: "Can I do this?" Try it. "I can't" Why not?

Comment: And, please, post one question per question. That's why they're called questions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're having trouble with, but if you'd tried to compile this code, you'd have found that

```
friend bool operator <(const firefly&) const;
```

is illegal: you can't have a `const` qualifier on a freestanding function. Also, `operator<` is a binary operator, so it should take two arguments, both of type `const firefly &`.

You can also implement `operator<` as a member function, as you suggest yourself, but then drop the `friend` declaration.

Apart from that, there's nothing wrong with your code, except maybe that sorting a vector of entirely equal elements is a waste of time.

Comment: Now I've tried to put the definition of the overloaded operator< in the global scope of the main, such as:

bool operator<(const firefly& rhs, const firefly& lhs)

      {
      
        float a, b;
        
        a = rhs.get_time(); b = lhs.get_time();
        
        return a < b;
        
        }. Then in the main() there'll be the sorting..but i can't compile.
However I don't want that the vector contains all equal elements, as you say: indeed the parametric constructor, inside of itself, assigns to the private member time_flash random values for each element..what did you think?

Comment: @MattF. You *must* tell us the compiler error. You said "it can't compile". Tell us everything you can. You might find it useful to copy your code to http://ideone.com/ and let it try to compile it for us - this will allow all of us to see the errors and it will allow you to show us exactly what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Excuse me but why you choose vector+customized sorting rather than set/map with a customized comparator?

Normally, we use vector mostly due to a requirement on random access its elements via index. If that's not the case and especially in your case, you need a sorted vector, I'd suggest the set/map.

Comment: Actually, a "map" based on `std::vector<T>` is bound to be **a lot** faster if you only need look-ups once it is setup. Even if it is necessary to do changes the performance of a sorted `std::vector<T>` can be superior to that of a `std::map<K, T>`, depending on the size and the number of changes compared to the number of look-ups. Admittedly, I haven't compared using a sorted `std::vector<T>` with an `std::unordered_map<K, T>`, however.

Answer (score -2):

For the second question you will have to pass the overloaded function to sort as an argument

sort (myvector.begin()+4, myvector.end(), myfunction);

Comment: Not if he provides operator<.